# How to connect the emitter of a transistor to the base of another transistor? (PNP)

Tags: transistors

I'm a bit new to circuitry, and recently I have been experimenting with transistors, attempting to create some logic gates. I realized however, that basically all of my logic gates output a positive voltage (the emitter receives current from a 5V battery), and if I were to connect two gates, I needed the outputs of the first gate to be used as inputs for the second gate (meaning that the positive current would have to flow into the base of the second gate). My question is, how can you do that? I have spent a lot of time looking into transistors, and it seems to me that only current coming from ground can go through the base of a PNP transistor.

I'm sorry if the problem is due to a major misunderstanding on my part, like I said, I am pretty new to circuitry.

Comment: The collector/emitter current of first transistor goes to the second transistor's base. review working of transistors again. it will help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor#Transistor_as_a_switch

Comment: In [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic), the connection is *not* between emitter and base.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Put schematics and define your question better.

Comment: @CL. what do you mean by that?

Comment: As shown on the page I linked to, a TTL output is the collector (or collector and emitter of two transistors for a totem pole), and a TTL input is an emitter. In the logic low state, current flows *backwards*. However, I am not implying that you *should* use TTL.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is **cascoding** two transistors as transistors can be CASCADED and CASCODED. that totally depends on the application
 here is a cascade example, as the output of the first transistor connected to the base of the second transistor
"The cascade of a Common Emitter amplifier stage followed by a Common Collector (emitter-follower) amplifier stage can provide a good overall voltage amplifier"

[image]

and here is the CASCODE example:

[image]

the advantage of using this configuration is to have higher input-output isolation, higher input impedance, higher output impedance, higher gain or higher bandwidth

as I can see from your question, you are dealing with logic gates, or you want to design logic gate. I guess this website is a good start

http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-3/cmos-gate-circuitry/

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electronic/emitfol.html for darlington coupling (at the bottom of the page).